# Show view attributes inspector in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Any idea how I make this window visible in xcode?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYUbw.png]

I want to change the orientation but I can't find the "Simulated Metrics" tab anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `Simulated Metrics` apply only to `UIViews` (if you don't use `Storyboards`) and `UIViewController` subclasses the easiest way is to select the view or controller and do this:
[image]

Comment: I thought that would only change the position of my sidebar. Thanks!

Comment: lol i can't believe i couldn't figure it out, i guess it's that developer thinking always looking for a complex way to show stuff instead of looking at the top right of the IDE and click on the sections (biggest button on screen besides run and stop and the big itunes status screen

Answer (score 12):

you only get this if you select viewController and select

View -> Utilities -> Show Attributes Inspector

Answer (score 2):

You must have a view controller selected and the Utilities panel displayed.